# Segmentation fault with gdb

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to learn C with the Kernighan and Ritchie book "The C programming language". As an exercice I am trying to program a vector multiplicator. I'm currently trying to collect two lines representing each a vector and then convert them into double. When running the program I get a segmentation fault.

If I comment out line 67 and uncomment line 66 (using `mycharcat()`), in `gdb` I get:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  0x0000000100003bc0 in mycharcat ()
```

If I comment out line 66 and uncomment line 67 (using `strncat()`), in `gdb` I get:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  0x00007fff20519552 in ?? ()
```

What could be a sound next step in this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXLINE 100
#define MAXDOUBLE 20


int mygetline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i;

  i = 0;
  while(--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
  {
    s[i++] = c;
  }
  if (c == '\n')
  {
    s[i++] = c;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}


void mycharcat(char s[], char t)
{
  for (; *s != '\0'; s++ )
  {
    ;
  }
  *s = t;
  s++;
  *s = '\0';
}

char myarray1 [][MAXDOUBLE] = {"", "", ""};
char myarray2 [][MAXDOUBLE] = {"", "", ""};
//int getvec(char *myarray[]);

int getvec(char **myarray)
{
  char line[MAXLINE]; 
  strcpy(line, "");
  int space_count, i;
  char doublechar[MAXDOUBLE];

  mygetline(line, MAXLINE);
  space_count = 0;
  i = 0;
  strcpy(doublechar, "");

  while(i<strlen(line)){
    if (isspace(line[i]) || line[i] == ',' )
    {
      //printf("space checked\n");

      if (isspace(line[i-1])!=1 && line[i-1] != ',' ){
        space_count++;
      }
      i++;
      strcpy(doublechar, "");
    }
    else if (isdigit(line[i]) || line[i] == '.')
    {
      //mycharcat(myarray[space_count], line[i]);
      strncat(myarray[space_count], &line[i], 1);
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Only enter digits, space or comma\n");
      return -1;
    }
  }
  printf("space_count: %d\n",space_count);
  for (i = 0; i<space_count; i++)
  {
    printf("myarray[%d]: %s\n", i, myarray[i]);
  }
  return 1;
}
 

int main()
{
  int nline = 0;
  while(nline < 2)
  {
    nline++;
    getvec(myarray1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your program is doing what you intend.  Let's look at your data and your logic.

```
char myarray1 [][MAXDOUBLE] = {"", "", ""};
```

This is an array of *N* arrays, each of size `MAXDOUBLE`.  *N* is 1, because the initializer list is 3 bytes: three `'\0'` characters.  The rest of `myarray1` will be zero-filled, per the C standard.

You can verify that by printing `sizeof(mayarray1)` and `sizeof(myarray1[0])`. You can compute *N* with `sizeof(mayarray1) / sizeof(myarray1[0])`.

In your program logic, you write to the array with

```
strncat(myarray[space_count], &line[i], 1);
```

but at no point do you ensure `space_count` is less than `N`.  That's a time-tested way to arrive at your problem and question: *which operation references an invalid location*?  Because I see `space_count++`, I'm pretty sure, without looking further, that at some point you reference `myarray1[1]` and exceed the limits of your program's memory space.

Some advice that may help you in your endeavor:

- Assert your preconditions.  **assert**(3) is your friend. Before writing to an array, assert that the index is in bounds.  Before writing through a pointer, assert that the pointer points to something valid, that it's not NULL and that it's between the beginning and end of an array.
- Define the variable you want to operate on with the types you want to use.  In your case, you want an array of `double`, so define that.  Then decide how to fill it.
- When reading text and converting it to numbers, use **getline**(3) to read a line at a time (if that's what you want) and **sscanf**(3) to convert the input text to one or more doubles.  That function reports how far it got with your input, so you can produce useful messages without fiddling with each character.

I think if you follow that plan, you'll find your program is easier to write and understand, and in general you'll spend less time asking why you're looking at `SIGSEGV` messages.